# How to selectively remove field in documents in MongoDB collection according to binary field size?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, updating

I found $binarySize, but it can only be applied on aggregate queries, which makes completely new collection, which is not the dataset itself I want to make changes to.

I don't see a way to use $binarySize with find().

My aggregate query is this:

```js
    db.releases_details.aggregate([
        { $project: { release_id: "$release_id", cover: "$cover", img: "$img", tracklist: "$tracklist", imageSize: { $binarySize: "$cover" } }  },
        { $match: { "imageSize": { $lt: 1775 } } }
    ])
```

Here's the sample data:

```json
{ "_id" : ObjectId("623ebe3315e29330ede4e631"), "release_id" : 43239, "cover" : BinData(0,"PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxh... (1,555 bytes)") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("623ebe3315e29330ede4e630"), "release_id" : 43238, "cover" : BinData(0,"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD... (42,200 bytes - image/jpeg)") }
```

If only I can set cover property to null wherever it is smaller than 1775 bytes?

Anyone did something similar?

Comment: The aggregate should have no issue with manipulating your target collection. Can your provide some sample json documents and the expected output so we can see how we can help?

Comment: Please don't put the updates in a comment. Instead, update your question with the new updates.

Comment: OK I deleted the comment, updated the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the manipulate the `cover` field with `$cond`. Then use `$merge` to update back into the collection with an aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "cover": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $lt: [
              {
                "$binarySize": "$cover"
              },
              1775
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$cover"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gywize2jqNw) for your reference.